# Python how to split a string into several phases

Tags: python

For example

```py
str1 = 'Polyphosphate + n H2O <=> (n+1) Oligophosphate'
str2 = '16 ATP + 16 H2O + 8 Reduced ferredoxin <=> 8 e- + 16 Orthophosphate + 16 ADP + 8 Oxidized ferredoxin'
```

How to split the `str1` into `'Polyphosphate', 'H2O', Oligophosphate'`, `str2` into `'ATP' 'H2O' 'Reduced ferredoxin' 'e-' 'Orthophosphate' 'ADP' and Oxidized ferredoxin'`.
Thank you!

Comment: The need is to list every compound in the chemical reaction equation。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expressions you can split on `<=>` or `+` to get the separate compounds with numbers.

Once you have them separated you can use `lstrip` to remove the preceding numbers (including `(n+1)` and the like) and `strip` to remove the succeeding spaces.

```
import re

str1 = 'Polyphosphate + n H2O <=> (n+1) Oligophosphate'
str2 = '16 ATP + 16 H2O + 8 Reduced ferredoxin <=> 8 e- + 16 Orthophosphate + 16 ADP + 8 Oxidized ferredoxin'

res1 = [i.lstrip(" 123456789n()+").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str1)]
res2 = [i.lstrip(" 123456789n()+").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str2)]

print(res1) # ['Polyphosphate', 'H2O', 'Oligophosphate']
print(res2) # ['ATP', 'H2O', 'Reduced ferredoxin', 'e-', 'Orthophosphate', 'ADP', 'Oxidized ferredoxin']
```

---

With your changing requirements:

> In some compound, it may also exist the number or some other char, for example, '5-Aminolevulinate' or '(+)-Bisdechlorogeodin'

Here's another slightly less nice solution with an extra complicated sample:

```
import re

str1 = 'Polyphosphate + n H2O <=> (n+1) Oligophosphate'
str2 = '16 ATP + 16 H2O + 8 Reduced ferredoxin <=> 8 e- + 16 Orthophosphate + 16 ADP + 8 Oxidized ferredoxin'
str3 = '5-Aminolevulinate + 8 Reduced ferredoxin <=> 8 e- + 16 Orthophosphate + (+)-Bisdechlorogeodin + (n+1) Oligophosphate'

res1 = [re.split(r"[^a-z] ", i)[-1].lstrip("n ").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str1)]
res2 = [re.split(r"[^a-z] ", i)[-1].lstrip("n ").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str2)]
res3 = [re.split(r"[^a-z] ", i)[-1].lstrip("n ").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str3)]

print(res1) # ['Polyphosphate', 'H2O', 'Oligophosphate']
print(res2) # ['ATP', 'H2O', 'Reduced ferredoxin', 'e-', 'Orthophosphate', 'ADP', 'Oxidized ferredoxin']
print(res3) # ['5-Aminolevulinate', 'Reduced ferredoxin', 'e-', 'Orthophosphate', '(+)-Bisdechlorogeodin', 'Oligophosphate']
```

---

To handle your now deleted comment with further possible requirements:

> During the experiment, there exist new compounds, for example ''2 GTP <=> Diphosphate + P1,P4-Bis(5'-guanosyl) tetraphosphate'', the compound is 'P1,P4-Bis(5'-guanosyl) tetraphosphate'

```
import re

str1 = 'Polyphosphate + n H2O <=> (n+1) Oligophosphate'
str2 = '16 ATP + 16 H2O + 8 Reduced ferredoxin <=> 8 e- + 16 Orthophosphate + 16 ADP + 8 Oxidized ferredoxin'
str3 = '5-Aminolevulinate + 8 Reduced ferredoxin <=> 8 e- + 16 Orthophosphate + (+)-Bisdechlorogeodin + (n+1) Oligophosphate'
str4 = '2 GTP <=> Diphosphate + 8 e- + 16 Orthophosphate + 12 (+)-Bisdechlorogeodin + (n+1) P1,P4-Bis(5\'-guanosyl) tetraphosphate'

res1 = [re.split(r"[^a-z\)]\)? ", i)[-1].lstrip("n ").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str1)]
res2 = [re.split(r"[^a-z\)]\)? ", i)[-1].lstrip("n ").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str2)]
res3 = [re.split(r"[^a-z\)]\)? ", i)[-1].lstrip("n ").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str3)]
res4 = [re.split(r"[^a-z\)]\)? ", i)[-1].lstrip("n ").strip() for i in re.split(r" \+ | <=> ", str4)]

print(res1) # ['Polyphosphate', 'H2O', 'Oligophosphate']
print(res2) # ['ATP', 'H2O', 'Reduced ferredoxin', 'e-', 'Orthophosphate', 'ADP', 'Oxidized ferredoxin']
print(res3) # ['5-Aminolevulinate', 'Reduced ferredoxin', 'e-', 'Orthophosphate', '(+)-Bisdechlorogeodin', 'Oligophosphate']
print(res4) # ['GTP', 'Diphosphate', 'e-', 'Orthophosphate', '(+)-Bisdechlorogeodin', "P1,P4-Bis(5'-guanosyl) tetraphosphate"]
```

(Note: I've added some arbitrary other stuff to the formula to try and make sure that it's generating the correct result in more cases, also note I won't necessarily have caught all edge cases, but it works for the examples given.)

Comment: In some compound, it may also exist the number or some other char, for example, '5-Aminolevulinate' or '(+)-Bisdechlorogeodin'

Comment: Thank you. During the analysis, I found if replace the ' ' of compounds in the in the chemical reaction equation, the problem will be simplified, how to do that. For example, the 'Reduced ferredoxin' becomes 'Reduced_ferredoxin', the 'P1,P4-Bis(5'-guanosyl) tetraphosphate' becomes 'P1,P4-Bis(5'-guanosyl)_tetraphosphate'. I use the 're.sub(r'[a-z()]\s[a-z()]', '_', str)', but this will delete the character adjacent the ' ', i.e. 'Reduced_ferredoxin' becomes 'Reduce_erredo.

Answer (score 0):

As you put it in the question, jsut use the string `split` method:

`phrases  = str.split(" + ")`

It outputs a list of substrings divided on the parameter passed as splitting token. If no parameter or "None" is passed, it will split the string on whitespace (either spaces, tabs or newlines).

The converse method `join` of strings can be used to re-assemble a string from such a list later:

`my_str = " + ".join(phrases)`

As a side note, avoid naming a variable `str` as it is the name of the string class in Python and it will be shadowed.

For further processing of each substring you can use a for loop, and reapply the split in each token, dropping the tokens that are you are not interested in. If these are all numbers and the `<=>` token, this would work:

```
raw_phrases  = str.split(" + ")
phrases = []
for phrase in raw_phrases:
    filtered = []
    for token in phrase.split():
        if not token.isdigit and token not in ("<=>",) : # extend the predicate to whatever other tokens you want to filter
             filtered.append(token)
    phrases.append(" ".join(filtered))
```

The splitting, filtering and rejoining loop above can be expressed in a single line of code with the use of list comprehensions:

```
phrases = [" ".join(token for token in phrase.split(" ") if  not token.isdigit() and token not in ("<=>",) ) for phrase in str.split(" + ")]
```

Comment: This only partially answers the question. It doesn't drop the numbers or the `<=>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as follows:

```
phrases = str.split(" + ")
```

To split on the common separator ' + ' between the phrases.

FYI: `str` is already used by the python standard library to denote the string type. I'd suggest you think of a different variable name.

Update:

As posted in a comment to the other answer, this will leave you with the `8`'s before some of the phrases. You can remove those by looping over `phrases`:

```
phrases = [phrase.strip("8 ") for phrase in phrases]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added a new example. I have tried this before.

Comment: You could chain the `.strip()` calls to remove all the known prefixes.